# Users don't see facebook app permissions when run it

Tags: web-applications, facebook-apps

Good day.
With my web application I allow my customers to publish photo albums on their facebook pages logging in a social network with own accounts. In order to make it, I have created a public facebook app and setted the customers as tester. For publish the album I have created a javascript routine. For some of them, when clck on a button of a web application that publish the album, the request to allow the app tyo make it not is displayed and the operation not is executed. Nothing javascript error appears on a browser console. The popup block in a browser is disabled. Why?
Best regards.
Stefano Errani

Comment: hard (aka impossible) to help with the information at hand. how about some code?

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet of javascript code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId : "<%=myfbappid%>",
        xfbml : false,
        version : "v2.11"
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    pubblicaFacebook();
}

function pubblicaFacebook() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
        var pageId = "<%=pageid%>";
        var accessToken = "";
        if (pageId == "me") {
            accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        }
        FB.api("/me/accounts", function(response) {
            for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                var p_id = response.data[i].id;
                if (pageId == p_id) {
                    accessToken = response.data[i].access_token;
                    break;
                }
            }
            FB.api("/<%=pageid%>/albums", "post", {message: messaggio, name: '<%=nomealbum%>', access_token: accessToken}, function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    var albumId = response.id;
                    if (albumId > 0) {
                        var fotos = "<%=foto%>";
                        var afoto = new Array();
                        var x = 0;
                        var i = 0;
                        while (fotos.indexOf("#", x) > 0) {
                            var y = fotos.indexOf("#", x);
                            afoto[i] = fotos.substring(x, y);
                            x = y + 1;
                            i++;
                        }
                        for (i = 0; i < afoto.length; i++) {
                            FB.api("/" + albumId + "/photos", "post", {message: "", url: afoto[i], access_token: accessToken});
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        } else {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    pubblicaFacebook();
                }
            }, {scope: "publish_actions,publish_pages,manage_pages"});
        }
    });
}
```